# Exponential function word problem

Tags: calculus

[image]

From this word problem  I know that I need to first plug in 99 into the average cost and I find my number to be 59.82083

And I know i need to do the derivative of the equation which is, but it isnt simplified, I have it simplified on my paper: [image]

When i plug in 99 into that derived formula i get -0.417544902

My question is, what do i do now? I have 2 numbers I need but im just confused at this last step, how do i find the marginal cost ______ dollars/(one unit of the product).

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pay more attention to the wording of the problem.  You're given the **average** cost and are asked to find the **marginal** cost; you made the mistake in thinking that you had to differentiate the average cost to get the marginal cost.

The first thing you need to do is find the cost function given that we know the average cost function.

Recall that average cost is defined as

$$\overline{C}(x) = \frac{C(x)}{x}$$

where $C(x)$ is your cost function.  So, from your problem, it follows that if the average cost function is

$$\overline{C}(q) = \frac{870}{q} + 3500\frac{e^{(3q+4)/820}}{q}$$

then the cost function $C(q)$ is

$$C(q) = q\cdot\overline{C}(q) = 870 + 3500e^{(3q+4)/820}.$$

Now you can go head and find the marginal cost when $q=99$; i.e. compute $C^{\prime}(99)$.

Comment: I understand what you are showing me but I am still somewhat confused when you mean compute C'(99), i still need to use the derived formula  dont i?

Comment: You'll need to differentiate the cost function $C(q) = 870 + 3500e^{(3q+4)/820}$ (which hasn't been done yet) and then plug in $q=99$.

Comment: Ahh that makes more sense, Thanks Christoper